# Should I be concerned by this discrepancy in my drive space?

Tags: hard-drive, macos

I was planning to delete a user account, and I noticed that it said that I don't have at least 87.1 GB of free disk space, even though my Macintosh HD shows that I have 159.4 GB free.  You can see the image below. Should I be concerned? What should I do?

[image]

**Some background:** I just reinstalled OS X El Capitan. I did this preemptively just in case something was wrong with the OS, because I had some issues with my computer hanging while trying to transfer a user account from an backup hard drive with the Migration Assistant app. Since it was hanging for many hours, I had no choice but to force-restart my computer during the migration process.

I'm running OS X El Capitan.

Comment: I'm rewriting my comment: Apparently purgeable space was introduced in Sierra, after El Capitan.

Comment: Ah my apologies!